# MSBuild of Visual Studio Fail Error MSB3231

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have solution contains over 100 project, I have define output folder and event post build with MSBuild Task in target file.
When I build solution alway ocurrs Error MSB3231.
Unable to remove directory "..\build\Client\Data". The directory is not empty. 
Please help me resolved this issue.
Thank you & Best Regards!

Comment: Which Task are you using for removing the directory? If it RemoveDir then make sure that the process that run the MSBUild has all rights on the folder to delete.

Comment: This is hard, if not impossible, to answer without more information: is the directory empty? Do you have multiple projects being built in parallel and they are all accessing that directory? Doe it occur when you build just one project? Etc..

Comment: @Quan Nguyen, what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?